# Mvvm uml diagram for google sample

Tags: android, mvvm, android-architecture-components

I'm studing the architecture design from google samples as reference :
https://github.com/android/architecture-samples/tree/todo-mvvm-databinding
it's difficult to understanding their code for beginner , by chance , I found MVP Uml ,it was really clear :
https://javaexpert.tistory.com/786
but they didn't do the Mvvm ,if any expert has any Uml for Mvvm that it can be help it'll be very useful
And Thank's .

Answer (score 2):

These are the best resources I have found for MVVM UML.

1. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T29YVrJSax0
2. https://www.raywenderlich.com/21792733-uml-for-android-engineers
3. https://github.com/asuslennikov/mvvm
4. https://github.com/weeeBox/mobile-system-design